# Mail() won't send in windows server2003

Tags: php, email, smtp, windows-server-2003

I installed PHP in windows server 2003. All the files are working fine except the mail issue. There is no problem in SMTP. Because I run the JSP project in the same server.In that mail function working fine. So where is the problem? And how can i manage? I set the SMTP server in PHP as

```
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the SMTP service need authentication? Maybe there is a setting in the JSP code which authenticates against the SMTP server? You could look at the JSP code to see if there is a different SMTP configuration.

Another reason could be that the SMTP allows only specific sender addresses/domains. Are the sender addresses of the PHP and JSP applications different?

Answer (score 0):

If  your smtp server is not exposed and protected behind a firewall you can allow relay and that should take care of it.

If not then verify you can  send the email you want using telnet